# Dynamically expanding scrollbar?

Tags: c++, dynamic, scroll, mfc, scrollview

So, I have been searching this on Stackoverflow, [CodeProject](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/262954), Google, [Microsoft](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/582159/MFCplus-plusHowplustoplusresizeplustheplusdialogpl), [...] for the past few hours. I cannot seem to find this.

- `CDialogEx`

  - `CFormView`

    - `CScrollbar`

**How can I re-size my `CScrollBar` dynamically, to expand (horizontally and vertically) to fit the content being drawn/added in it ? (`CButton`, `CEdit`, etc. are added inside at run-time).**

All attempts with `->MoveWindow` and `->SetWindowPos` have failed.
I have tried various times overloading the `OnSize` and `OnVScroll` functions... low success.

Does the `CFormView` may cause the problem ? Should I rather draw the `CScrollBar` in `CDialogEx` ? Would that work ? It's my first time using `CFormView`, I'm not very familiar with it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scrollbar size should be set to match the maximum extent of the window contents, i.e. the range of image that the user can see by scrolling. This is independent of the size of the window.  See the documentation for CScrollView::SetScrollSizes

Comment: Great, thank you very much... (leaving this in case someone else may need it too). 1. Set size to a default maximum and store the `SIZE` in the class. 2. Check if newly added content will be greater than the current limit, if so: 3.1 Use `CScrollView::SetScrollSizes` to expand it. - Yes I need it this way.